# Filter out the least cloudy images in Sentinel Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am trying to filter out the least cloudy Sentinal 2 images and display them on as per the AOI boundary. I am working on the following code, but it is not filtering out the least cloudy images or any method to remove the cloud from images. I had gone through several posts but not found any solution yet.

```
var shp=ee.FeatureCollection('users/Desktop/AOI');
Map.addLayer(shp);
var sentinel=ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filterDate('2019-12-10','2019-12-30')
.select(['B8','B4','B3','B2']).filterBounds(shp).sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', false);
var s2a=sentinel.mosaic().clip(shp);
print(sentinel);
//var clipped = sentinel.map(cloudmask).map(clipper);
//var leastCloudy = ee.Image(sentinel.sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE').first());
Map.addLayer(s2a,{min:0, max:4000}, 'Output');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have your ROI, but I made another to make your code reproducible. Rather than using the `sort()` function, try instead setting a threshold percent cloud cover that you're happy with and remove all imagery that has too much cloud cover:

```
var Sample = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[-119.22, 38.06], [-119.23, 37.97], [-119.01, 37.91], 
  [-118.89, 37.93], [-118.85, 38.02], [-119.01, 38.09],
  [-119.22, 38.06]]
]);

// Generate Region of Interest
var shp = ee.FeatureCollection(Sample);

Map.addLayer(shp);
var sentinel = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2019-12-10','2019-12-30')
  .select(['B8','B4','B3','B2'])
  .filterBounds(shp)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20));

var s2a = sentinel.mosaic().clip(shp);
print(sentinel);
//var clipped = sentinel.map(cloudmask).map(clipper);
//var leastCloudy = ee.Image(sentinel.sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE').first());
Map.addLayer(s2a,{min:0, max:4000}, 'Output');
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfectly working